# Access classes from subpackage in Java

Tags: java

I have organized my project's packages as

```
com.myproject
com.myproject.field
com.myproject.helper
com.myproject.messages
```

The project is a component of a bigger context. The only entrypoint to the component is in Main.class in `com.myproject`

As part of good practice I would like to make only Main.class public. But using this structure it is not possible. The only way I can think of is, that I put everything in a flat structure and make everything protected - but then it is 0 organzed.

Am I missing something abount accessibility/visibility here regarding Java?
Thanks

Comment: You *could* use modules introduced in Java 9...

Comment: "But using this structure it is not possible" why it is not possible? The question is missing the description of the actual issue you seem to have.

Comment: @aled Because private (or package-private) classes in the sub-packages can’t be accessed by adjacent sub-packages.

Comment: plus they can not be accessed by Main.class one level up.

Comment: The question doesn't mention private classes. I believe is up to the OP to clarify the details for reproduction.

Comment: @aled It does by implication: “make *only* Main.class public” — this clearly implies that the other classes will need to be private or package-private. Those are the only choices.

Comment: I think Java 9+ modules are *exactly* the correct use case for that. With them you can have any subset of your classes exposed as usable APIs and the rest for "internal" use.

Comment: Thank you very much, now you guys mentioned them, it rings a bell. Honestly I have no experience using them. Can they be used in a bigger context where they have never been used before in any component? Just thinking out loud, I am going to look into the docs...

Answer (score 0):

See comments:
You could use modules introduced in Java 9...